# Why oplog search is taking too long on Primary

Tags: mongodb

Our mongo log is showing this: We have 4 set replica set

```
Thu Jul 31 03:31:33.940 [conn2117994] getmore local.oplog.rs query: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1406791765000|9 } } cursorid:6285460755727107211 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:111 nreturned:0 reslen:20 5011ms
Thu Jul 31 03:31:33.976 [conn2117999] getmore local.oplog.rs query: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1406791765000|9 } } cursorid:6285462893114917907 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:111 nreturned:0 reslen:20 5011ms

Thu Jul 31 03:31:38.952 [conn2117994] getmore local.oplog.rs query: { ts: { $gte: Timestamp 1406791765000|9 } } cursorid:6285460755727107211 ntoreturn:0 keyUpdates:0 locks(micros) r:95 nreturned:0 reslen:20 5011ms

ecset01:PRIMARY> db.printReplicationInfo()
configured oplog size: 83927.3283203125MB
log length start to end: 2399486secs (666.52hrs)
oplog first event time: Tue Jun 24 2014 22:58:20 GMT-0400 (EDT)
oplog last event time: Tue Jul 22 2014 17:29:46 GMT-0400 (EDT)
now: Tue Jul 22 2014 17:29:46 GMT-0400 (EDT)
ecset01:PRIMARY>
```

Please let me know if this is a issue or we need to reduce the oplogsize.

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior. Replication uses a tailable cursor to read from the oplog, with the awaitdata option. This means that if there is no data that satisfies the query(e.g. no documents with ts greater than the timestamp passed in) it will wait for several seconds - roughly 5 seconds which is why you see the query time of 5011 ms. This is not a cause for concern - all it means is that you have no recent updates. If you were to add/modify/delete a document you would then see a getmore entry returning much faster.

Details on the tailable cursor and awaitdata options at the wire-protocol layer:

http://docs.mongodb.org/meta-driver/latest/legacy/mongodb-wire-protocol/?pageVersion=106#op-query

You may find this discussion interesting:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/E7BSv624nBg